# helper function returning a result before logic is applied in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a controller that calls a helper function to do some work but only problem is helper returns prematurally before it executes its logic.

What I want is to wait for the helper function to finish its tasks and return me a result.

While I am at it, is it advisable to use async on controller methods, as shown below?

Controller:

async MoveItems(req, res, next) {

```
const data = req.body; // json
const total_items = data.length;

let status = 400;
let err_msg = "";

if (total_items == 0 || data.constructor != Array) {
  err_msg = "Sorry, you must post/upload json";
} else {


  for (let counter = 0; counter <= total_items - 1; counter++) {
    // check the record now



    const validItem = await Helpers.validateItem(
      data[counter]
    );
    ValidItem is always now false if it is valid

    if (!validItem) {

      err_msg = `Invalid item found on row ${counter + 1}`;
      break;
    }
  }


}

res.status(status).send({ detail: err_msg });
```

}

My Helper:

```
export default {
  async validateItem(record) {


    const ItemID = +record["ItemID"];


    let response = false;

    db.Item.findAll({
      where: { ItemID },
      limit: 1
    })
      .then(item => {


        if (item.length === 1) {
         response = true;
        } 
      })


    return response; // always false
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use result of `db.Item.findAll`, so you function returns false all the time. The correct solution is to `await` result of `db.Item.findAll` call:

```
export default {
  async validateItem(record) {
    const ItemID = +record["ItemID"];

    let items = await db.Item.findAll({
      where: { ItemID },
      limit: 1
    });

    return (items.length === 1);
  }
};
```

Another problem is that, your code hidden asynchronous call. You called async function and returned some result from the function. But result of async call or possible thrown error were unprocessed and unhandled.

Also instead of `db.Item.findAll` you can use `db.Item.count` or something like this (I don't know what ORM do you use), that returns item count.

Comment: Thanks alex. items.length is undefined is what i am getting. console.log(items) shows it is a promise, which don't have length I suppose.

Comment: @NieSelam If `db.Item.findAll` returns a promise, `let items = await promise` waits until promise will be fulfilled and initialize `items` to fulfilled result of promise. Are you sure that u use my code properly?